# Как удалить пустые элементы в массиве вместе с ключами?

Tags: массивы, php

unset удаляет только значение, а я хочу удалить еще и ключи.
Что использовать для этого?
Также хотелось бы узнать функцию, которая удалит все это дело полностью сама, без циклов, думаю, что такая есть, не так ли?

Comment: unset() разве не полностью удаляет массив ?

Comment: @Rnddev, unset может применяться и на отдельных ключах массива, фантастика:

    unset($array['key']);

Comment: @Etki я уверен более чем на 100% что вы не поняли мой комментарий

Comment: я себя каким-то тупым ощущаю 

http://ideone.com/IYjJZI

Comment: если хочется чтобы числовой массив "схлопнулся" есть [array_slice()](http://php.net//manual/ru/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1)

```
$new_array = array_filter($old_array, function($element) {
    return !empty($element);
});
```

2)

```
$new_array = array_diff($old_array, array(''));
```

Comment: В каких случаях  `empty( $x)` !=  (FALSE === $x)` ?

Можно не указывать ф-ю, т.к. по умолчанию `array_filter()` удаляет элементы, которые `== FALSE`:

    $new_array = array_filter( $old_array);

Comment: Ну, вообще, 0 это тоже false, поэтому тут можно еще проверку на 0 добавить.

Comment: Зачем?

    empty( 0); // TRUE
    0 == FALSE; // TRUE

Я просто предлагаю сократить код, убрав ненужную ф-ю проверки.

Comment: Иначе будут удаляться элементы массива со значением 0. Думаю, автор этого не хочет.

Comment: Понял. Т.е. так предлагаете?  ([ideone](http://ideone.com/pZnxMG))

    $new_array = array_filter($old_array, function($element) {
        return ( 0 === $element) ? TRUE : !empty($element);
    });

Comment: Можно и так. Все зависит от того, что автор подразумевает под пустым элементом - пустую строку или элемент, для которого empty возвращает true. Если первое, то проще воспользоваться вторым вариантом, либо возвращать что-то такое: return $element !== '' в первом варианте.

Answer (score 2):

В зависимости от того, что считается "пустым" элементом, можно еще такой вариант предложить:

```
<?php

$arr = ['', 'a',0, 2, 'd',false, 'p', '', null, 'c', 3,0];
var_dump($arr);
$new_arr = array_diff($arr, array('', NULL, false));

var_dump($new_arr);

// результат

Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => a
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 2
    [4] => d
    [5] => 
    [6] => p
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => c
    [10] => 3
    [11] => 0
)
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 2
    [4] => d
    [6] => p
    [9] => c
    [10] => 3
    [11] => 0
)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Пригодилось. Правда ключи не по порядку, но вообще ок работает!

Answer (score 2):

Зашел посмотреть на решение достаточно насущной проблемы. Беглым взглядом окинул топик и увидел, что нормального решения пока нет. Сочинил следующее:

```
 foreach($old_array as $element) {
                if(!empty($element)){
                    $new_array[] = $element;
                }
            }
```

Не изящно, но очень просто и, главное, работает :)

Comment: Рабочий из представленных =) Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Хотелось бы отметить что далеко не всегда такого кода достаточно:

```
$new_array = array_diff($old_array, array(''));
```

Например так мы например можем нарваться на неприятности:

```
$new_array = array_diff(explode("/", "/level1/level2/"), array(''));
```

На выходе мы получим

```
Array
(
    [1] => level1
    [2] => level2
)
```

Хотя на самом то деле хотели получить

```
Array
(
    [0] => level1
    [1] => level2
)
```

По этому для таких случаев используем:

```
$new_array = array_values(array_diff(explode("/", "/level1/level2/"), array('')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $file = 
            array_filter($file, 
                function($element)
                {
                    $element = trim($element);
                    if(strlen($element))
                        return true;
                }
            );
```

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте:

```
unset($arr[0]); sort($arr);
```

И все, ключей пустых нет.

Comment: Так вы затираете/изменяете все ключи массива http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ba8ade518869931dc8daf25591c38731cbf000a

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?